# Is there any material which has same refractive index as the air?

Tags: optics, refraction

If there is then what would happen if light passes through it?

Comment: Adding to John Rennie's answer I can only think of one other class of materials that come close to the optical density of gases: aerogels. If you haven't seen them, yet, they are truly "aerial"! https://www.google.com/search?q=aerogel&newwindow=1&safe=off&espv=2&biw=2168&bih=976&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoA2oVChMInamX7oHxxwIVCC-ICh1FhALO&dpr=0.9

Comment: How do you think mirages come into being?

Comment: Are you looking for a Solid, Liquid, or Gas, and at what temperature/pressure range? Also, what level of refractive index matching is required, e.g. reflectivity at a flat interface? As air is a moderately complex gas mixture there are likely to be other gas mixtures with similar refractive index - they just mix though - But there are scenarios where it is effective, such as an N2 'window tube' between a cold test area and a hot environment.

Answer (score 9):

The refractive index of a material differs from the vacuum because of interactions of the light with electrons in the material. So to a first approximation the refractive index is related to the electron density. Air has a low refractive index because it has a low density so it doesn't have many electrons per cubic metre.

There are no solids or liquids with a refractive index the same as air, mainly because there aren't any solids or liquids with a density as low as air. So whether there are any objects with the same refractive index as air depends on what you mean by *object*. A cloud of a different gas in air will have a very similar refractive index, but does a cloud of gas count as an *object*?

An object with the same refractive index as air would be invisible because no light would be scattered at the air/object boundary. That's assuming of course that the object is transparent and isn't coloured.

Although it's not really what you asked, you might be interested to read about [metamaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial_cloaking). This is a way of making something that manipulates light to behave as if it is invisible.

Answer (score 5):

Please see http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Reprints/2007-Xi-JQ-et-al-%28Nature-Photonics%29-Thin-film-with-low-refractive-index-for-broadband-elimination-of-Fresnel-reflection.pdf (nature photonics VOL 1 MARCH 2007 p. 176 ) - pretty dense substance with a refractive index 1.05, close to that of air; low broadband reflection.

Let me note that if you need a refractive index close to that of air in a narrow band only, you can use materials with an absorption line close to your narrow band.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any material which has same refractive index as the air?

No there isn't. There are more answers to this question which address that.

---

> If there is then what would happen if light passes through it?

Let's assume that such an object, say a fabric, exists. According to the lens maker's equation, $$\frac1f=\left(\frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1}-1\right)\left(\frac1{R_1}-\frac1{R_2}\right)$$ For air, $\mu_1 \approx 1$ and same goes for our 'object'. $\mu_2 \approx 1$. Plugging these values in the equation, we get $$\frac1f=0 \Rightarrow f=\infty$$ Et voilà we have a plane mirror (focal length of plane mirror is $\infty$)! So essentially your 'object' becomes invisible.

Light won't pass through it but reflects off.